# What kind of pepper is this?

Tags: identification, peppers, chili

Friend gave me some seeds that she had stored for a while. I planted them and they grew into this beautiful chili plant. We have no idea what kind of pepper it is exactly.

The fruit is relatively small, and as of late it's been turning from green to purple'ish.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Where did your friend get them?

Comment: @Shule From a bolivian greengrocer that's no longer around :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark but if I am right, lucky you!  NuMex Twilight or Capsium annuum 'NuMex Twilight'.  You'll start seeing reds and oranges soon if so.

[NuMex Twilight](https://shopcart.nmsu.edu/shopcontent/15/twilight.jpg)

Or this could be Bolivian Rainbow, starting purple and then turning red because the other is showing different colors in all new peppers.

[Bolivian Rainbow pepper](http://www.chileplants.com/images/chiles/bolivian-rainbow-pepper-plants.jpg)

Or this could be Centennial Blue

[Centennial Blue Pepper](http://www.chileplants.com/images/chiles/centennial-rainbow-pepper-plants.jpg)

Looking as if you can expect high Scoville units of heat regardless.

Comment: Could be a Bolivian rainbow, could be! Mainly because the fruit doesn't grow much bigger than what you see for the most part :-)

Comment: Bolivian Rainbow peppers I've had always have purple flowers.

Comment: That is a big point renesis!  Purple potatoes have blue or purple flowers.  The three peppers I cited are but a start.  Doubt they are correct...did notice the grey blue leaves with the other purple peppers but these leaves are normal green. What did you think of those peppers?  How hot were they?  Were they tasty?  Do you roast your peppers?

Comment: @Morgan  Mr. Computer Programmer!  Computer Programmers make great gardeners.  In my experience!  In fact they seem to be drawn to plants.  I would love it if you could send pictures in a week or two.  Someone else who has grown purple peppers might recognize a better variety.   They are all Capsium annuum...what have you used for fertilizer?  For my own info?  Where are you growing them?  In the garden, in a grow room with artificial lighting?  A fan will become your friend, shortly.  Helps with fungus as well as white fly...etc.

Comment: @stormy yeah, the leaves of the Rainbows are a bluish-green. The peppers themselves aren't very flavorful, medium-hot. Good substitute dried for red pepper flakes, also pickled some with a mix of other peppers. I have two potted plants right now that have been going for about 3 years.

Comment: Where is it you live renesis.  Are you in some subtropical place?

Comment: @stormy Yes, I'm a programmer and a Ms.! :-) I'm a very, very amateur plant lover. You'll be surprised to hear that I didn't use a fertiliser. I've been growing these peppers in the living room, next to a large window. They get around 6-9h of direct sunlight daily. I water them whenever I notice the soil is dry to the touch, usually a day and a half give or take. Luckily I don't get white fly on my indoor plants, so that's one less thing to worry about!

Comment: I would also give your plant a little shake to help pollinate the flowers.  Maybe take a soft, little paint brush to brush pollen to flowers?

Comment: Some day not today you will need to add fertilizer to your potted plants.  They aren't showing any deficiencies or excess.  Add another picture in a week or two!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, I've been hand pollinating these peppers. It's almost habit now. I sit next to it and if I notice any new flowers, I give them a little rub. By the way, what type of fertiliser do you recommend for these peppers?

Comment: For real, you are pollinating them? You are a gardener for sure.  I recommend Dr. Earth's 5-5-5 after the first up potting.  I've been using 'Growilla' 2-5-4  during the flowering and fruiting stages.  Osmocote 14-14-14  will last 4 to 6 months use half of what they recommend.   Make sure to check  your potting soil that you used?  Some come with fertilizer and as great as your plants look, that didn't happen without chemistry  from somewhere, grins.  Right now I would not add a thing, they look perfect.

Comment: @stormy, yup, CA SF bay area. I was even able to leave a pineapple out over the winter! (Its not particularly happy about it, but its too big to bring inside anymore...)

Comment: @stormy Here's an update. Some of the peppers are turning red :-) https://imgur.com/a/8Y27mqy

Comment: I vote for Bolivan Rainbow!  Happiness!  Ms. Morgan!  Grins!

Comment: Truly, be HONEST, you've not fertilized at all?  NOT AT ALL?  Fertilizer just has to be in the bag of soil you used.  These are ALMOST too green but the balance of the macro chemicals (nutrients) is just right for you to be getting such a harvest!  It is always a great thing for newbie gardeners to have such great success...I am sure we'll be hearing from you in the future with questions.  The sooner you ask the better!

Comment: Your plants are so dang healthy!  Good job Morgan!